# Homography transformation of image

Tags: java, image-processing, homography

Here is my sample image

[image]

I want to transform the image as follows according to the red marked point.

[image]

I implemented the formula described here : http://www.corrmap.com/features/homography_transformation.php

But my output is:

[image]

There are too much black noise in the output image.
Here is my java code

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import Jama.Matrix;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageWarp {
        private double x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4,
                        Y4;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            ImageWarp iw = new ImageWarp();

            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\mohar\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Test3\\src\\notebook.jpg"));
            ArrayList<Coordinate> coords = new ArrayList<>();
            coords.add(new Coordinate(39, 206));
            coords.add(new Coordinate(218, 29));
            coords.add(new Coordinate(541, 153));
            coords.add(new Coordinate(417, 417));

            BufferedImage output = iw.getCropedImage(img, coords, 500, 500);
            ImageIO.write(output, "jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\mohar\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Test3\\src\\output.jpg"));
        }

        public BufferedImage getCropedImage(BufferedImage imgBuffer,
                        ArrayList<Coordinate> cornersCordinate, int imageWidth,
                        int imageHeight) throws IOException {

                x1 = Math.abs(cornersCordinate.get(0).getX());
                y1 = Math.abs(cornersCordinate.get(0).getY());
                x2 = Math.abs(cornersCordinate.get(1).getX());
                y2 = Math.abs(cornersCordinate.get(1).getY());
                x3 = Math.abs(cornersCordinate.get(2).getX());
                y3 = Math.abs(cornersCordinate.get(2).getY());
                x4 = Math.abs(cornersCordinate.get(3).getX());
                y4 = Math.abs(cornersCordinate.get(3).getY());
                X1 = 0;
                Y1 = 0;
                X2 = imageWidth - 1;
                Y2 = 0;
                X3 = imageWidth - 1;
                Y3 = imageHeight - 1;
                X4 = 0;
                Y4 = imageHeight - 1;

                double M_a[][] = { { x1, y1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -x1 * X1, -y1 * X1 },
                                { x2, y2, 1, 0, 0, 0, -x2 * X2, -y2 * X2 },
                                { x3, y3, 1, 0, 0, 0, -x3 * X3, -y3 * X3 },
                                { x4, y4, 1, 0, 0, 0, -x4 * X4, -y4 * X4 },
                                { 0, 0, 0, x1, y1, 1, -x1 * Y1, -y1 * Y1 },
                                { 0, 0, 0, x2, y2, 1, -x2 * Y2, -y2 * Y2 },
                                { 0, 0, 0, x3, y3, 1, -x3 * Y3, -y3 * Y3 },
                                { 0, 0, 0, x4, y4, 1, -x4 * Y4, -y4 * Y4 }, };

                double M_b[][] = { { X1 }, { X2 }, { X3 }, { X4 }, { Y1 }, { Y2 },
                                { Y3 }, { Y4 }, };

                Matrix A = new Matrix(M_a);
                Matrix B = new Matrix(M_b);
                Matrix C = A.solve(B);
                double a = C.get(0, 0);
                double b = C.get(1, 0);
                double c = C.get(2, 0);
                double d = C.get(3, 0);
                double e = C.get(4, 0);
                double f = C.get(5, 0);
                double g = C.get(6, 0);
                double h = C.get(7, 0);

                int width = imgBuffer.getWidth();
                int height = imgBuffer.getHeight();

                BufferedImage output = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight,
                                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                                if (isInside(i, j)) {
                                        int x = (int) (((a * i) + (b * j) + c) / ((g * i) + (h * j) + 1));
                                        int y = (int) (((d * i) + (e * j) + f) / ((g * i) + (h * j) + 1));
                                        int p = imgBuffer.getRGB(i, j);
                                        output.setRGB(x, y, p);
                                }
                        }
                }

                return output;
        }

        private boolean isInside(int x, int y) {

                double apd = Math.abs(0.5 * (x1 * y + x * y4 + x4 * y1 - x * y1 - x4
                                * y - x1 * y4));
                double dpc = Math.abs(0.5 * (x4 * y + x * y3 + x3 * y4 - x * y4 - x3
                                * y - x4 * y3));
                double cpb = Math.abs(0.5 * (x3 * y + x * y2 + x2 * y3 - x * y3 - x2
                                * y - x3 * y2));
                double pba = Math.abs(0.5 * (x * y2 + x2 * y1 + x1 * y - x2 * y - x1
                                * y2 - x * y1));
                double rec = Math.abs(0.5 * (x1 * y2 + x2 * y3 + x3 * y4 + x4 * y1 - x2
                                * y1 - x3 * y2 - x4 * y3 - x1 * y4));

                if ((apd + dpc + cpb + pba) > rec) {
                        return false;
                } else {
                        return true;
                }
        }

}

class Coordinate {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Coordinate(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }



    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }


}
```

Comment: So, for each point in the original image you're calculating its position in the destination image? That would miss a lot of points. It would be better to calculate the value of each pixel in the destination image interpolated from the original image. For that you'll need to apply the inverse transform. I'm sure there's a duplicate question around here, I'm just trying to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by [beaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377097/beaker),

> For each point in the original image you're calculating its position in the destination image. That would miss a lot of points. It would be better to calculate the value of each pixel in the destination image interpolated from the original image.

To avoid this circumstance you can use backward mapping `(x’,y’)` to `(x, y)` for each point.

Here's your modified workable code

```
public class ImageWarp {
    private double x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4,
            Y4;

    public BufferedImage getCropedImage(BufferedImage imgBuffer,
            ArrayList<Coordinate> cornersCordinate, int imageWidth,
            int imageHeight) throws IOException {

        X1 = Math.abs(cornersCordinate.get(0).getX());
        Y1 = Math.abs(cornersCordinate.get(0).getY());
        X2 = Math.abs(cornersCordinate.get(1).getX());
        Y2 = Math.abs(cornersCordinate.get(1).getY());
        X3 = Math.abs(cornersCordinate.get(2).getX());
        Y3 = Math.abs(cornersCordinate.get(2).getY());
        X4 = Math.abs(cornersCordinate.get(3).getX());
        Y4 = Math.abs(cornersCordinate.get(3).getY());
        x1 = 0;
        y1 = 0;
        x2 = imageWidth - 1;
        y2 = 0;
        x3 = imageWidth - 1;
        y3 = imageHeight - 1;
        x4 = 0;
        y4 = imageHeight - 1;

        double M_a[][] = { { x1, y1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -x1 * X1, -y1 * X1 },
                { x2, y2, 1, 0, 0, 0, -x2 * X2, -y2 * X2 },
                { x3, y3, 1, 0, 0, 0, -x3 * X3, -y3 * X3 },
                { x4, y4, 1, 0, 0, 0, -x4 * X4, -y4 * X4 },
                { 0, 0, 0, x1, y1, 1, -x1 * Y1, -y1 * Y1 },
                { 0, 0, 0, x2, y2, 1, -x2 * Y2, -y2 * Y2 },
                { 0, 0, 0, x3, y3, 1, -x3 * Y3, -y3 * Y3 },
                { 0, 0, 0, x4, y4, 1, -x4 * Y4, -y4 * Y4 }, };

        double M_b[][] = { { X1 }, { X2 }, { X3 }, { X4 }, { Y1 }, { Y2 },
                { Y3 }, { Y4 }, };

        Matrix A = new Matrix(M_a);
        Matrix B = new Matrix(M_b);
        Matrix C = A.solve(B);
        double a = C.get(0, 0);
        double b = C.get(1, 0);
        double c = C.get(2, 0);
        double d = C.get(3, 0);
        double e = C.get(4, 0);
        double f = C.get(5, 0);
        double g = C.get(6, 0);
        double h = C.get(7, 0);


        BufferedImage output = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < imageHeight; j++) {
                    int x = (int) (((a * i) + (b * j) + c) / ((g * i) + (h * j) + 1));
                    int y = (int) (((d * i) + (e * j) + f) / ((g * i) + (h * j) + 1));
                    int p = imgBuffer.getRGB(x, y);
                    output.setRGB(i, j, p);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

For further understanding you can see [this](http://what-when-how.com/introduction-to-video-and-image-processing/geometric-transformations-introduction-to-video-and-image-processing-part-2/).

Comment: Thanks, it saves my day.